# abp io AbpDataFilterOptions

Tags: abp

i am trying to configure new data filter for IMayHaveCreator. I saw example for ISoftDelete and did the same thing.

in MyAppEntityFrameworkCoreModule ive added another configure method for Filter but it does not work

```
public class SimplyAirEntityFrameworkCoreModule : AbpModule
    {
        public override void PreConfigureServices(ServiceConfigurationContext context)
        {
            SimplyAirEfCoreEntityExtensionMappings.Configure();
        }

        public override void ConfigureServices(ServiceConfigurationContext context)
        {
            context.Services.AddAbpDbContext<SimplyAirDbContext>(options =>
            {
                /* Remove "includeAllEntities: true" to create
                 * default repositories only for aggregate roots */
                options.AddDefaultRepositories(includeAllEntities: true);
            });

            Configure<AbpDbContextOptions>(options =>
            {
                /* The main point to change your DBMS.
                 * See also SimplyAirMigrationsDbContextFactory for EF Core tooling. */
                options.UseNpgsql();
            });

            Configure<AbpDataFilterOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultStates[typeof(IMayHaveCreator)] = new DataFilterState(isEnabled: true);
            });
        }
    }
```

am i doing something wrong

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to implement it. solution was to add override for `CreateFilterExpression` and `ShouldFilterEntity` methods in `dbContext` for that interface